# (Flutter) Custom Builder for List of Strings

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `List` which is of type `Strings`. This list can have any number of items in it.

Lets say this is my list:

```
[Dwayne Johnson, Akshay Kumar, Will Smith, Matt Damon, Salman, Someone Else]
```

I tried this:

```
Text(NamesList.toString());
```

but it just displayed the list as it is.

I want to display the list like this:

[image]

There can be 1,2 or even 3 items displayed depending on their length.

I even though of using `ListView.builder` or `GridView.builder`, but the items are not identical in length, so it doesn't work for me.

What should I do here?

Comment: You could use `Wrap`: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html

Comment: @JordanDavies Will a Listview.builder work inside it?

Comment: u can use a wrap and inside use a list.foreach() and create the item have in your list.

Comment: @ArgelBejarano How can I populate `children<Widget>` of Wrap with `forEach`?

Comment: you can do it in differente ways, this is with dart 2.3 spreads 
```
Wrap(
                children: <Widget>[
                  for (String item in list)
                     Text(border),
                ],
              ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a quick walk-around to do it:

```
List<String> famous = ["Dwayne Johnson", "Akshay Kumar", "Will Smith", "Matt Damon", "Salman", "Someone Else"];

Widget stringWithBullet() {
    String people = "";
    for (var item in famous) {
      people += item += " • ";
    }
    return Text(
      people.substring(0, people.length - 3),
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 18,
      ),
    );
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Material(
    child: Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40),
        child: stringWithBullet(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Is going to look like this, you can add `textAlign: TextAlign.center` to center the text:

[image: String with Bullets]

You could play around using `"\n"` to break lines every time you have a **name + last name** to make sure it goes to a new line.